# Is it possible to make a contextually-sensitive python context manager that saves, modifies and restores state?

Tags: python, state, contextmanager, stateful

I have a pair of python functions that currently flip a global variable between two values. I would like to turn them into context managers so I can use them as `with` blocks, setting the variable inside the block, but restoring it after. Here's the desired behaviour:

```
>>> MODE
'user'
>>> mode_sudo()  # Sets MODE to 'sudo'...
>>> MODE
'sudo'
>>> mode_user()  # Sets MODE to 'user'...
>>> MODE
'user'
>>> with mode_sudo():
...    print MODE
'sudo'
>>> MODE
'user'
```

Is such a chimera possible?

**UPDATE:** Just for clarity, here's the context-manager-only implementation:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def mode_sudo():
    global MODE
    old_mode = MODE
    MODE = 'sudo'
    yield
    MODE = old_mode

@contextmanager
def mode_user():
    global MODE
    old_mode = MODE
    MODE = 'user'
    yield
    MODE = old_mode
```

Calling these w/o a with keyword returns a generator. Is there a way to get the mode-flipping behavior with both the plain-vanilla function call and the chocolate context manager?

Comment: What's the point of testing the value of `MODE`?

Comment: Not much, I suppose. The edge case evaporates upon scrutiny. :P

Comment: I've removed the silly value test.

Comment: What about `def set_mode(mode):` and afterwards `MODE = mode`? So you only have to have the code once...

Comment: That might be a better design in some cases, but in this case I happen to be trying to work context managers into an existing code base in a backward-compatible fashion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
class mod_user:

    def __init__(self):
        global MODE
        self._old_mode = MODE
        MODE = "user"

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kws):
        global MODE
        MODE = self._old_mode

MODE = "sudo"

with mod_user():
    print MODE  # print : user.

print MODE  # print: sudo.

mod_user()
print MODE   # print: user.
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. And no dependency on contextlib. That's nice. :)

Comment: Devious but nice, I've never thought to use a constructor to fake a callable.

Comment: Probably not a good thing to do all the time, but in this case, the effect is definitely worth it.

Comment: As to naming the context-manager class `mod_user` instead of `ModUser`, there doesn't seem to be a strongly-enforced [naming convention for context-manager classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948457/naming-convention-for-context-classes-with-blocks). But it seems more Pythonic to write: `with ModUser() as mod_user: ...`

Answer (score 2):

Easy way:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager
def mode_user():
    global MODE
    old_mode = MODE
    MODE = "user"
    yield
    MODE = old_mode
```

idem for `mode_sudo()`. See [the doc](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/contextlib.html) for more details. It is actually a shortcut for the whole "definine a class that implements `__enter__` and `__exit__`"-thing.

Comment: Whoops, I just posted an edit that looks almost exactly like your code. :) But this answers only half the question. If you just call this implementation w/o a with statement, you'll get a generator.

Comment: The point is when you do `with mode_user()` it calls the `__call__()` method of `mode_user`, exactly like if you simply call `mode_user()` outside the `with` clause. I can't think of a way to discriminate whether you're in a `with` clause.

Comment: We were both boxed in by `contextlib` and its generator shortcut. @mouad's pure-protocol implementation gets around that: `__exit__` never gets called except in a with statement.

Comment: @David I don't see so - if I try the said code above and call mode_user(), I get a <contextlib.GeneratorContextManager object> which is not a generator, it is even not iterable.

If you don't like this behaviour, you can, of course, craft your own class like above.

Comment: @glglgl Well, looks like you're right--it's not iterable. However, the main point of my objection still stands: nothing happens until `__enter__` is invoked, making it unhelpful for this particular use case.

Comment: Aahh, ok. Now at a second glance, I see the difference: the mode switch happens in `__init__()`, not in `__enter__()` here. Then it is clear. Thanks for pointing out!