# Naming convention for context-manager classes ("with" blocks)

Tags: python, naming-conventions, contextmanager

Is there a general naming convention for classes or functions that are meant to be used in `with` block such as

```
with CreateSomeContext() as x:
    ...
```

? Something that signals that the class or the result of a function should be used with `with`?

Comment: AFAIK there is none.. what we have so far is for functions and variable names use `this_is_a_function_or_variable` and for classes (types) use `ThisIsAClassObject` and for constants use `FULL_CAPITALS`.

Comment: AFAIK no since `with` can be used for a lot of different purposes. Some put the word `context` explicitly in the name, however this happens mostly when `with` is the *only* place where you want to use such a class. There is a number of classes that can be used with `with` without (no pun intended) the word "context" in their names: from files to `warnings.catch_warnings` etc.

Answer (score 5):

In [the respective PEP 0343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#examples), there is a mention of two conventions:

> The tense used in the names of the example contexts is not
>       arbitrary. Past tense ("-ed") is used when the name refers to an
>       action which is done in the `__enter__` method and undone in the
>       `__exit__` method. Progressive tense ("-ing") is used when the name refers to an action which is to be done in the `__exit__` method.

Comment: Since the convention suggested on the PEP is not even followed by the standard library (see PEP example `stdout_redirected` and stdlib `contextlib.redirect_stdout`), I'd say this convention was not accepted/largely adopted.

Comment: @igortg This may be, but nevertheless it is a convention (or two), but not a binding one.

Answer (score 3):

There's no naming convention (`open`, `socket.create_connection`, `urllib.request.urlopen` all return context managers which can be used with `with`) but context managers will have the  `__enter__`  and `__exit__` methods.

**Note**: in the case of `open("file", "w")`, the return value (the file object) is the context manager, *not* `open`.